# Presidential Middle Names

Tags: cryptic-crosswords

<sub>This puzzle is part of the [Monthly Topic Challenge #16: Restricted Title: xkcd 2000-2500](https://puzzling.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/7528/monthly-topic-challenge-16-restricted-title-xkcd-2000-2500).</sub>

---

Each down clue in this crossword is missing one middle name of a US president.<sup>1</sup> The missing names are below, listed in order of prettiness to honour the [xkcd comic](https://xkcd.com/2393/) this is based on.<sup>2</sup> Find a place for each name in the clues (marked by two question marks), and solve the crossword.

```
GAMALIEL
ROBINETTE
DELANO
ULYSSES
BAINES
HENRY
DAVID
EARL
WALKER
JOHN
HOWARD
ALAN
SIMPSON
S.
ABRAM
WOODROW
RUDOLPH
QUINCY
KNOX
MILHOUS
HUSSEIN
BIRCHARD
```

[image: Empty crossword grid]
[Solve on Penpa+](https://tinyurl.com/yqog4q7q)

**Across**
7. Decisionmakers enter house (5)
8. Devoted university by port city in Old America (8)
10. The Rev's grim confusion – pulling rabbits out of hats? (5,6)
12. Special, unknown spot (3)
14. Man was seated next to another's dog (8)
17. Film featuring Sandra Oh displaying skimpy swimwear (6)
19. Nice change, once Native American's spoken (3)
20. Mules I trained to give breakfast? (6)
22. Bats liberate city near Toledo (6)
23. Gaming company donated $1,000 for water (3)
25. LA County is kind of mean? (6)
26. Smash, shorty? Er, that's what she said! (8)
28. King meeting queen for a meal (3, *abbr.*)
30. Invested in atom bomb? A dilemma for literary hermit (3,8)
34. On two occasions, I visited tortured lovers and relatives of filmmaker Lawrence? (8)
35. Turkic leader from the East – famous Central Asian (5)

**Down**
1. ?? flees Palestinian Authority group responsible for hits (4)
2. Fellow accompanying ?? regularly has just-in-time Tex-Mex food (6)
3. Cut like ??'s nose – fit, trimmed at the top (4)
4. Director of disreputable ?? Automobile finally caught (4)
5. ??: "It's, oddly, a cause of disagreements." (4)
6. ??'s pair is in sleep – could one count sheep in these? (4)
9. States backed by ??'s ultimate authority (3-2)
11. The men behind Gandalf and Goldfinger are a couple ?? butchered, dodging edges of blade (4)
13. Mary Jane used the ?? (4)
15. ?? of the *Midsomer Murders* is one large character (5)
16. Hotel assistant turned up like the author of ?? (5)
17. Near ??'s birthplace, an ancient civilization put together a place for medics to work (5)
18. ?? at first discarded broken girder? That's even less interesting! (5)
21. "Small injection," admitted ??, "that's something that can pierce the skin." (4)
24. Hallelujah! ?? arrested seeker of violent revenge (4)
25. Male Spaniard's father meeting bishop near Scottish lake deserted by ??, essentially (5)
27. Upcoming art film in two parts had her seek revenge against title character played by ??, causing emotional scars (6)
29. Pound ?? half dead (4)
30. Branch of Texan tech firm granted opening to cover Stone production with one-letter title (short for "??") (4)
31. ??, having lost game, exhausted with cross leftist (4)
32. ??'s chief consumed herbal drink (4)
33. Concerning home ?? emptied out (2,2)

---

<sub>1. Some of these are actually first names in the sense that they were the given name preferred by that person. They are, however, all middle names in the sense of not being the person's first given name.

2. The list is, of course, incomplete. It is outside the scope of this puzzle to place the missing CALVIN, CLARK, FITZGERALD, HERBERT, JEFFERSON and WILSON on their appropriate spots on the list. This is left as an exercise for the reader.</sub>

Comment: This is quite tough. It's been a battle to get to an almost complete grid, but I'm still missing two answers, and am not sure of the wordplay on a couple of others.

Comment: @fljx I'm actually glad whenever I can trip up experienced solvers, it doesn't happen that often! Somehow my first thought still tends to be that I've made some error and the puzzle is horribly broken... I'd be interested to know which clues you got stuck on.

Comment: The two I was missing were 1D and 7A. It didn't help that I got 3D wrong initially, and left my first answer in the grid (didn't even notice until I saw Stiv's post) and was trying to find a 7A answer with the wrong last letter.  31D was one of the wordplays I couldn't see - I wasn't 100% sure I had the middle names the right way round that for that and 1D, and the yellow cartoon family never crossed my mind (not sure why, I should have seen that one). The other was 23A, where I saw Electronic Arts (E.A) as the gaming company which left me scratching my head over "donated $1000" for  the "S".

Comment: And, I had to google most of the film/TV references, as that's just an area I'm weak in, so I was surprised that that I managed to resolve all of those (apart from 31D...).

Answer (score 12, accepted):

A great challenge, for both the solver and the setter, I'm sure! (Pleasingly pangrammatic too, in that all letters of the alphabet appear in the completed grid - just another constraint for the setter to have to work by!)

The resolved grid:

> [image: Resolved grid]

And clue explanations:

> **Across:**
>  7. Decisionmakers | enter | house (5) **BOARD** = triple def
>  8. **Devoted** university by port city in Old America (8) **[UXORIOUS](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/uxorious)** = U (university) + [XO](https://camus.fr/en/blogs/news/la-classification-et-l-age-des-differents-types-de-cognacs-vs-vsop-xo-xxo) (old) + [RIO](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rio_de_Janeiro) (port city) + US (America)
>  10. [The Rev](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/William_Archibald_Spooner)'s grim confusion – **pulling rabbits out of hats?** (5,6) **MAGIC TRICKS** = Spoonerism of ‘tragic mix’
>  12. Special, unknown **spot** (3) **SPY** = SP (Special) + Y (unknown)
>  14. Man was seated next to another's **dog** (8) **ALSATIAN** = AL + SAT + IAN
>  17. Film featuring Sandra Oh displaying **skimpy swimwear** (6) **SPEEDO** = [SPEED](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Speed_(1994_film)) (Film featuring Sandra [Bullock]) + O (Oh)
>  19. **Nice change**, once Native American's spoken (3) **[SOU](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/French_sol)** (a coin in [Nice in] France) = “[sioux](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sioux)”
>  20. Mules I trained to give **breakfast?** (6) **MUESLI** = MULESI*
>  22. Bats liberate **city near Toledo** (6) **MADRID** = MAD (Bats) + RID (liberate)
>  23. Gaming company donated $1,000 for **water** (3) **SEA** = SE(-g)A
>  25. **LA County** is kind of mean? (6) **[PARISH](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_parishes_in_Louisiana)** = PAR-ISH (kind of mean/average)
>  26. Smash, shorty? Er, that's **what she said!** (8) **[HERSTORY](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/herstory)** = SHORTYER*
>  28. King meeting queen for a **meal** (3, abbr.) **BBQ** = [B.B.](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/B._B._King) (King) + Q (Queen)
>  30. Invested in atom bomb? A dilemma for **literary hermit** (3,8) **[TOM BOMBADIL](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tom_Bombadil)** = _TOM BOMB A DIL_
>  34. On two occasions, I visited tortured lovers and **relatives of [filmmaker Lawrence](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Laurence_Olivier)?** (8) **OLIVIERS** = LOVERS* containing ‘I’ twice
>  35. Turkic leader from the East – famous Central Asian (5) **[TIMUR](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Timur)** = T(-urkic) + [RUMI](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rumi)< &lit!
>
>  **Down:**
>  1. *S* flees Palestinian Authority **group responsible for hits** (4) **[ABBA](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ABBA)** = [ABBA(-s)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mahmoud_Abbas)
>  2. Fellow accompanying *ALAN* regularly has just-in-time **Tex-Mex food** (6) **FAJITA** = F (Fellow) + A_A_ containing JIT (just-in-time)
>  3. **Cut** like *[RUDOLPH](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rudolph_the_Red-Nosed_Reindeer)*'s nose – fit, trimmed at the top (4) **EDIT** = (-r)ED + (-f)IT
>  4. **Director** of disreputable *KNOX* Automobile finally caught (4) **EXEC** = _E _X _E + C (caught)
>  5. *EARL*: "It's, oddly, **a cause of disagreements**." (4) **[ERIS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Eris_(mythology))** = E(-a)R(-l) I(-t)S
>  6. *WOODROW*'s pair is in sleep – **could one count sheep in these?** (4) **ZOOS** = (-w)OO(-drow) in Z’S (sleep)
>  9. States backed by *DELANO*'s ultimate **authority** (3-2) **SAY-SO** = SAYS (States) + (-delan)O
>  11. **The men behind Gandalf and Goldfinger** are a couple *BAINES* butchered, dodging edges of blade (4) **IANS** ([McKellen](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ian_McKellen) and [Fleming](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ian_Fleming)) = (-b)AIN(-e)S*
>  13. Mary Jane | used the *JOHN* (4) **WEED** = ddef
>  15. *[HOWARD](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Laura_Howard)* of the *Midsomer Murders* | is [one large character](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Large_Family) (5) **LAURA** = ddef
>  16. Hotel assistant turned up **like the author of *[ULYSSES](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ulysses_(novel))*** (5) **IRISH** = H (hotel) + [SIRI](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Siri) (assistant), all reversed
>  17. **Near *[HUSSEIN](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Saddam_Hussein)*'s birthplace, an ancient civilization** put together a place for medics to work (5) **[SUMER](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sumer)** = SUM (put together) + E.R. (a place for medics to work)
>  18. *GAMALIEL* at first discarded broken girder? That's **even less interesting!** (5) **DRIER** = (-g)IRDER*
>  21. "Small injection," admitted *HENRY*, "that's **something that can pierce the skin**." (4) **SHIV** = S (Small) + H ([Henry](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Henry_(unit)) + [I.V.](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Intravenous_therapy) (injection)
>  24. Hallelujah! *ABRAM* arrested **seeker of violent revenge** (4) **[AHAB](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Captain_Ahab)** = _AH AB_
>  25. **Male Spaniard**'s father meeting bishop near Scottish lake deserted by *BIRCHARD*, essentially (5) **PABLO** = PA (father) + B (bishop) + LO(-ch) (Scottish lake, with (-bir)CH(-ard) removed)
>  27. Upcoming art film in two parts had her seek revenge against title character played by *[DAVID](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/David_Carradine)*, causing **emotional scars** (6) **TRAUMA** = ART< + UMA (Thurman, of *Kill Bill*)
>  29. **Pound** *QUINCY* half dead (4) **QUID** (pound, in the UK) = QUI(-ncy) + D (dead)
>  30. **Branch** of Texan tech firm granted opening to cover Stone production with one-letter title (short for "*WALKER*") (4) **TWIG** = [TI](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Texas_Instruments) + G(-ranted) containing [W](https://www.imdb.com/title/tt1175491/) (which is also short for ‘Walker’ in [this President’s name](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/George_W._Bush))
>  31. *SIMPSON*, having lost game, exhausted with cross **leftist** (4) **[MARX](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Karl_Marx)** = [MAR(-g_e)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Marge_Simpson) + X (cross)
>  32. *MILHOUS*'s chief consumed **herbal drink** (4) **[MATE](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mate_(drink))** = M_ + ATE (consumed)
>  33. **Concerning** home *ROBINETTE* emptied out (2,2) **[IN RE](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/In_re)** = IN (home) + R_E